# A inequality about infinite product $\prod\limits_{i=1}^\infty(1-\frac1{2^i})$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Show that
$$\prod_{i=1}^\infty(1-\frac1{2^i})>0.288$$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78689/the-limit-of-infinite-product/

Comment: This product also appeared [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491948/whats-the-limit-of-1-1-21-1-41-1-8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the required bound, you need to modify my argument from the other answer:
$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty \left({1-{1\over 2^k}}\right) 
\geq  \prod_{k=1}^5\left({1-{1\over 2^k}}\right) \left(1-\sum_{k=6}^\infty{1\over 2^k}\right) 
={315\over 1024}\cdot {15\over 16}={4725\over 16384}\approx .28839.$$